# Power Bi DAX: Weekly Column for only working days

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need help working out the working days so i can calculate a weekly target by:

target / Working days in a Month (Total) = Daily Target

Daily Target * Working days in a week = Weekly Target

My target is set on the 1st of the month so that is why i need to spread it across weeks.

My columns:

- Date
- Month
- Year
- Week Number (1-52)
- Week day (1-7)
- Weekinmonth
- Working day (1 & 0)
- Day in Month (1-31)

What i need:

I need to list out the dates filtering out the working dates as another column (Does not show the dates that are on the weekend, these will be blank), need to return the working days as 1-31 as another column (same as the DAY function) so i can make a MAX formula to get the Working days in a month to by divided by the target to make the daily target. I am unsure how i will get the Working days in a week.

Can anyone help??

Comment: I had this kind of problem, initially, I used some measures to "emulate" the daily values, but in the end, the best solution has been to split the "Monthly Target" on a "Working-Day basis" before loading the data (or while loading them) and then link them to the calendar table by date. This will spare you lots of possible issues. That said I will write some measures that might help you.

Comment: I'm always open to find new solutions if it means it makes everything much easier. Please show me the measures when you have put them together thank you!

Comment: After thinking about how to make the measures, I remembered that I used this pattern: https://www.daxpatterns.com/budget-patterns/ . the article describes the problem and solution (using measures) better than me